# I am trying to prove that a series has only non-integer entries after an element in the series.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to prove that the series $a_n=\frac{6n}{4+n}$ has non-integer values for n>20.  I attempted doing this by induction but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: you can prove that the value is increasing but always remains smaller than $6.$ So, as soon as it exceeds $5...$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\,\ \dfrac{6n}{n+4}\, =\ 6 - \dfrac{24}{n+4}$